# Como gerar UUID's/GUID's com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, uuid

Preciso criar UUID's/GUID's com Javascript, porém não achei nenhuma função na documentação. Conhecem/recomendam alguma biblioteca existente, que gere UUID's válidos e satisfatoriamente aleatórios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versões baseadas em [`crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) podem garantir uma menor taxa de colisão do que `Math.random()`.

```js
function uuid() {

    // Retorna um número randômico entre 0 e 15.
    function randomDigit() {
    
        // Se o browser tiver suporte às bibliotecas de criptografia, utilize-as;
        if (crypto && crypto.getRandomValues) {
        
            // Cria um array contendo 1 byte:
            var rands = new Uint8Array(1);
            
            // Popula o array com valores randômicos
            crypto.getRandomValues(rands);
            
            // Retorna o módulo 16 do único valor presente (%16) em formato hexadecimal
            return (rands[0] % 16).toString(16);
        } else {
        // Caso não, utilize random(), que pode ocasionar em colisões (mesmos valores
        // gerados mais frequentemente):
            return ((Math.random() * 16) | 0).toString(16);
        }
    }
    
    // A função pode utilizar a biblioteca de criptografia padrão, ou
    // msCrypto se utilizando um browser da Microsoft anterior à integração.
    var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
    
    // para cada caracter [x] na string abaixo um valor hexadecimal é gerado via
    // replace:
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-8xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/x/g, randomDigit);
}

console.log(uuid());
```

Você pode perceber que a string de retorno possui 2 valores fixos, 4 para o 3o bloco e 8 para o 4o. Isso é parte da [especificação para GUIDs randômicas versão 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609091/1845714)

Comment: Tem como dar uma explicada sobre o funcionamento do algoritmo?

Comment: Como funciona direito o `crypto.getRandomValues`? É compatível com vários browsers?

Comment: @jbueno Explicação em comentários, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário A maioria dos browsers modernos suporta a biblioteca `crypto`.

Comment: Ótimo +1 @OnoSendai

Comment: @OnoSendai acho que melhor que isso só fazendo uma chamada AJAX e gerando server side kkkk muito obrigado, acho que serve perfeitamente pros meus propósitos

Answer (score 1):

Realizei algumas pesquisas e encontrei algumas funções que podem lhe ajudar.

Para gerar o UUID você pode usar a função abaixo:

```
function create_UUID(){
    var dt = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (dt + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        dt = Math.floor(dt/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r :(r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
console.log(create_UUID());
```

Para gerar o GUID pode ser feito conforme abaixo:

```
function S4() {
    return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
}

function create_GUID(){
    return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0,3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
}

console.log(create_GUID());
```

Referências:

http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-23.php
http://guid.us/GUID/JavaScript

Comment: E como isso funciona?

Comment: As funções create_UUID() e create_GUID() retornam uma string. Então é só você chamar a função conforme fiz em console.log(create_UUID()) que ela já irá gerar o código aleatório.

Comment: Quero saber como funciona o algoritmo que cria o UUID.

Comment: Nos links que passei nas referências tem mais detalhes sobre o algoritmo.

Comment: Mas eu não falo inglês.