# Gerar um e-mail randômico em Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Gerar um e-mail randômico

Estou precisando gerar um e-mail randômico, para quando vou criar o cadastro de um usuário no meu sistema, toda vez que eu for inserir um novo usuário eu preciso gerar esse e-mail random.

Abaixo o trecho de código onde eu vou lançar o email randômico gerado.

```
 formGroup.email = "emailrandômicoaqui",
```

Ele precisa ser nesse estilo: string@string.com

Por que foi uma regra de negócio que criamos, que o email do usuário sera definido em outro formulário de outra parte, pelo administrador, então na hora do cadastro, não deixamos um e-mail ser repetido e não deixamos ele ir vazio. Por isso preciso gerar e-mail random.

Comment: O mail tem algum dominio? ou é basicamente uma string random e unica que procuras?

Comment: E não tem regra pra gerar isso? Só precisa ser _random_? O email pode ser algo como `01530a65-4205-40c3-a321-1d65c0fc4501@algumacoisa.com`?

Comment: Sim amigos, pode ser qualquer coisa randômica no estilo hsadsahudsa@hdsuahdu.com, agradeço muito a ajuda. @Sergio

Comment: @jbueno tem regra sim, tem que ser no padrão valido, por que o loopback não deixa passar no formato inválido.

Comment: Então é só gerar um guid/uuid. Veja como criar isso em JavaScript [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198003/18246)

Comment: @jbueno obrigado, acho que isso vai servir, vou dar uma debugada no código e testar aqui